Three JS shadows not showing?
I have made a interactive 3d model on my website with ThreeJS, and everything work other than shadows. I can't make shadows work. I am new to ThreeJS so it could be I am skipping some important part.
Here is my JS code:
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { GLTFLoader } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

let mouseX = window.innerWidth / 2;
let mouseY = window.innerHeight / 2;
let object;
let controls;
let objToRender = 'dino';

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.getElementById("container3D").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.z = objToRender === "dino" ? 4 : 500;

const topLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 3); 
topLight.position.set(-1.05307, 0.107503 , 4.52525 );
topLight.castShadow = true;
scene.add(topLight);

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, objToRender === "dino" ? 1 : 1);
scene.add(ambientLight);

renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; 

const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load(
    `models/${objToRender}/scene.gltf`,
    function (gltf) {
        object = gltf.scene;
        object.castShadow = true; 
        object.receiveShadow = true; 
        scene.add(object);
        animate(); 
    },
    function (xhr) {
        const percentage = (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100).toFixed(2);
        console.log(percentage + '% loaded');
        // Show loading progress somewhere in your UI
        document.getElementById("loadingProgress").innerText = `Loading: ${percentage}%`;
    },
    function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
);

if (objToRender === "dino") {
    controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    if (object && objToRender === "eye") {
        object.rotation.y = -3 + mouseX / window.innerWidth * 3;
        object.rotation.x = -1.2 + mouseY * 2.5 / window.innerHeight;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});

document.onmousemove = (e) => {
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;
};


And here is picture from my website:
enter image description here
I tried asking chatgpt for help , but he only gave me fixes that didnt work.

One solution you could try is making a copy of your objects and instead of using a normal material on the copy use the shadow material. This material is specifically used for making shadows.
Three.js ShadowMteral

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
